# Android Vitals and non-Play app distribution channels

Tags: android, google-play

My organisation distributes an android app (same package name / application id, signed with same private key) using two channels:

1. through the Play Store
2. from our own hosting server

The usage and diagnostics information in the Play Developer Console is very helpful.

Basic question: Will Android still collect and send to Play (possibly using the application ID to recognise that the app is available on Play Store) usage and diagnostics information from the devices that **downloaded the app from our server** (instead of from Play Store), assuming the device has been set-up to share usage and diagnostics data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment yes, if the APK is absolutely identical. However it may not if the APK differs. And it is not guaranteed to continue to work in future.